# Jquery ,PHP Post Json data to an external url

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I have the  following jquery function which is supposed to post data to a php function which in the  process it passes it to the external script for processing. 
Below is my jquery function :

```
  function order_confirmation(json) {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>home/confirm_order_received/",
                        data: json,
                        contentType: 'application/json',
                        dataType: 'json',
                        success: function (data) {
                            console.log(data);
                        },
                        failure: function (errMsg) {
                            console.log(errMsg);
                        }
                    });
                }
```

This function is supposed to pass the json data to my php function which is below here :

```
  function confirm_order_received() {
        $json = $this->input->post('json');
        // Initialize curl
        $curl = curl_init();
        $externalscriptaddress = "http://197.237.132.178/api/order/order_upsert";
        // Configure curl options
        $opts = array(
            CURLOPT_URL => $externalscriptaddress,
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
            CURLOPT_POST => 1,
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $json
        );

        // Set curl options
        curl_setopt_array($curl, $opts);

        // Get the results
        $result = curl_exec($curl);

        // Close resource
        curl_close($curl);

        echo $result;
    }
```

I have a problem of how I am supposed to access the  data from the  php side, I have tried accessing it through the  post : `$json = $this->input->post('json');` and passed it to the   `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $json` but I get an error since nothing has been passed. Please advise how can i pass the  json data to an external script?

Comment: where you are assigned json variable in order_confirmation()

Comment: can you show what is the value in json variable that you have used in javascript

Comment: Try var_dump($_POST); and inspect whats being posted. Also try  var_dump($this->input->post());

Answer (score 0):

For getting raw post data (in your case) use `file_get_contents("php://input")`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `data: json,` you should use `data: "json:json",`

Using just `data: json,` will post the data, but it will not be assigned to a key. To access the data ou need to assign it to a key. By using `data: "json:json",`, you can access it with `$json = $this->input->post('json');`